# Modular exponentiation. Replacing exponent.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've come across an exercise whose solution is given and I don't understand it.
Basically you have to compute: 
$$\prod_{i=1}^{100} 2^i\pmod 9$$
And so what they do is calculate the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{100} i = 5050$. So the result is $2^{5050}\pmod 9$.
Now, they say that since $2^6\equiv 1\pmod 9$ and $5050\equiv 4\pmod 6$, we have 
$2^{5050}\equiv 2^4\pmod 9$ and $2^4\equiv 7\pmod 9$. And that's the answer.
I have several questions:

- I don't understand the replacement of the exponent. They just
  substitute 5050 for 4. Can you do this all the time? It has something
  to do with 6, because they  calculate $5050\pmod 6$. Does it matter
  that $2^6\equiv 1\pmod 9$? If the result were different than 1 would
  the substitution have been different?

If you were able to provide a step by step explanation I would be so grateful.

Cheers,

lkese3ker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity $2^6 \equiv 1 \mod 9$ is useful here because it makes you compute the following:
$$2^{5050} \equiv 2^{6k+4} \equiv (2^6)^k \cdot 2^4 \equiv 1^k \cdot 2^4 \equiv 2^4 \mod 9$$
So it enables you to compute large numbers $\mod 9$ by reducing it to a much smaller number.

Concerning the question "Does it matter that $2^6 \equiv 1 \mod 9$?": Yes, it does.
E.g. the relation $2^7 \equiv 2 \mod 9$ is also true but it's not that useful since it only gives
$$2^{5050} \equiv 2^{7k+3} \equiv (2^7)^k \cdot 8 \equiv 2^k \cdot 8 \mod 9$$
So it leaves you to compute $2^k$ (in this case $k=721$) $\mod 9$ which is still a pretty large number.

So the key issue when solving such a problem is about finding a (hopefully small) number $m$ such that $2^m \equiv 1 \mod 9$. The famous [Theorem by Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) tells you that $m=\phi(9)=6$ will work where $\phi(n)$ denotes [Euler's Totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful. However, correct me if I'm wrong, I think you slipped a mod 8 in the second displayed equivalence.

Comment: @lkese3ker: Thanks for that remark. I edited.